# Why does position of console.log cause loop destructuring an array to crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This function reverses an array through de-structuring by reversing positions of elements in the array.

```
function reverseArray(arr){
    for(let i=0; i < arr.length/2; i++){
        // console.log('why does it fail')
        [arr[i], arr[arr.length - i - 1]] = [arr[arr.length - i - 1], arr[i]]
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(reverseArray([1,2,3]))
```

It works well but if I un-comment the console.log line in the loop, it throws this error:

```
[arr[i], arr[arr.length - i - 1]] = [arr[arr.length - i - 1], arr[i]]
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
```

If I move the log statement after the array destructure it works fine. I tried this in node 8.15.1, 11.3.0, & 12.2.0. What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Always use semicolons unless you're *absolutely certain* of what you're doing, and even then, omitting them can easily trip you up. Your code evaluates to `undefined[arr[i], arr[arr.length - i - 1]]` -> `undefined[3]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance adding the semi colons does correct the behavior. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Because there's no semicolon, the `[` on the next line is interpreted as part of the same statement. See the linked question - a semicolon does not automatically get inserted.

Comment: @Todd http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons